# How to change model using directive and referencing element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a textbox in my page that has a custom autocomplete directive:

```
<input type="text" auto-complete ng-model="variant" value="{{variant}}"/>
```

The problem I am having is that when a user selects a value from the autocomplete menu, ng-model does not update.

I decided to change the model in the ng-blur directive. I tried:

```
<input type="text" auto-complete ng-blur="variant=element.value" ng-model="variant" value="{{variant}}"/>
```

That did not work. Is there any way to accomplish this without writing a custom directive?

Comment: please provide a plunker

Comment: my autocomplete is pulling from a database

Comment: Could you please create a plunker with fake data then?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" auto-complete ng-blur="variant=$event.target.value" ng-model="variant" value="{{variant}}"/>
```

Here is a **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/enq3s62h/)**